# How can I pass registered variable as array in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to list the files in a directory and copy to some other directory.

This is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: testserver
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: list files
    command: " ls /root/"
    register: r
  - debug: var=r

  - debug: msg="item.item={{item.item}}, item.stdout={{item.stdout}}, item.changed={{item.changed}}"
    with_items: "{{r.results}}"
```

This is the error I am getting:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'results'"}

Comment: `results` is only valid when you register the value(s) of loop

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to list the files in a directory and copy to some other directory.

1. [Don't parse `ls` output!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/133107) Neither in Ansible, nor anywhere else.
2. Don't use `command` module for what Ansible offers a native one.

Ansible has a [`find` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/find_module.html) which returns a list of files. In your case:

```
- name: list files
  find:
    paths: /root
  register: my_find

- debug:
    var: item.path
  with_items: "{{ my_find.files }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `debug` task there that shows you the contents of the variable `r`.  Do you see a key named `results`?

You only see the `results` key (and need to use `item.item`) when are have registered values in a loop, as described [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop).  You're not doing that, so the structure of `r` will be much simpler.

If you're trying to iterate over the lines of the `ls` output, you probably want:

```
- debug: 
    msg: "filename={{item}}"
  with_items: "{{r.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: ---
- hosts: testserver
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: list files
    command: "ls /root/"
    register: "r"

  - debug: var=r

  - debug: msg={{ item.item }}
    with_items:
      - "{{r.stdout_lines}}"

Comment: Yes, `item.item` is giving you the same error for the same reason. You'll note in my example here I'm not using that.